# Postfix flush changes messages date

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm using postfix with dovecot as smtp/imap server stack.
Quotas are configured in dovecot for users, but i'm facing a date problem:

When messages are kept in postfix queue, frequently cause of imap quotas, the message finally delivered is dated with the date/time of the flushed queue moment, and not with the initial mail one.

Is there any configuration to keep the original sent date/time of the messages?